# Extracting wanted numerical values from strings in Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I have two strings:

```
['Renewables\n', '17.9% (3,951 MW)\n']
['Solar\n', '27.4% (1,081 MW)\n', 'LATEST SYSTEM\n', 'GENERATION\n', '4,738 MW\n', 'THERMAL GENERATION\n', '(COAL, GAS, OTHER)\n', '54 %\n', 'RENEWABLE\n', 'GENERATION\n', '47.61 %\n']
```

But the only data I want from each is the numerical value of the percentage at the end of each string e.g 17.9 and 47.61, I want to take these numbers and use them in a follow up program where an outcome will be determined depending on which number is larger, as they are the results of a web scraping tool.

How do I extract just these values as floats so I can use them going forward?

**Edit**

Just to make it clear, I only want the last percentage values of each string, any MW values or previous percentage values are not wanted.

Comment: So you don't want 27.4%?

Comment: No just the last numerical values on each string

Comment: These are lists not strings

Comment: `17.9%` is in your list of wanted values. Please [edit] your question and add some more detail, as well as any attempt you have of your own.

Comment: It's really hard to find a general solution for this problem without just one example.

Comment: This is data that I have taken from a text file, using the readlines() command, that I created from a web scraper. My problem is that the data is constantly changing, and any attempt I have made has failed miserably as I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re
s = ['Renewables\n', '17.9% (3,951 MW)\n']
s1 = ['Solar\n', '27.4% (1,081 MW)\n', 'LATEST SYSTEM\n', 'GENERATION\n', '4,738 MW\n', 'THERMAL GENERATION\n', '(COAL, GAS, OTHER)\n', '54 %\n', 'RENEWABLE\n', 'GENERATION\n', '47.61 %\n']
final_results = [float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+(?=\%)|\d+\.\d+(?=\s\%)', i[-1])[0]) for i in [s, s1]]
```

Output:

```
[17.9, 47.61]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without regex, but it is very specific to your case.

The code checks for % in string, if found splits and extracts the number before that.

```
examples = ['Solar\n', '27.4% (1,081 MW)\n', 'LATEST SYSTEM\n', 'GENERATION\n', '4,738 MW\n', 'THERMAL GENERATION\n', '(COAL, GAS, OTHER)\n', '54 %\n', 'RENEWABLE\n', 'GENERATION\n', '47.61 %\n']
output = []

for each_string in examples:
    if "%" in each_string:
        number = each_string.split("%")[0].strip(" ")
        output.append(number)

#output = ['27.4', '54', '47.61']
```